# ¿Cómo puedo incrementar el valor de un campo por cada año que pasa (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql

Como puedo hacer una suma en MySQL que me permita incrementar el valor de un campo en "1" al pasar un año.

Por ejemplo:

"Hoy 30 de marzo de 2018" tengo 5 perros...

Entonces al pasar un año "30 de marzo en 2019" debo tener 6 perros.

La consulta sería algo así...
Micampo fecha lo tengo para saber el día que ingrese al usuario y el número de perros

select Id, Nombre, Perros, Fecha from Usuario;

```
    1   Ben  5 30/Marzo/2018
```

Y al pasar un año habré incrementado en 1 sólo a los perros

```
    1   Ben  6 30/Marzo/2018
```

Quiero imaginar que lo que se hace es actualizar el campo

Ejemplo de como me lo imagino que sería, Pero como lo pongo en un trigger y que se ejecute cada año que pasa de manera automática

```
    update Usuario set Perro=Perro+1 where "todos los usuarios";
```

Comment: podrías crearte un código en un archivo php que ejecute la acción y activarlo con un cron en tu panel web, tambien en el mismo codigo puedes validar el tiempo transcurrido en la fecha de esa manera si ya paso el año, le sumas 1, por otro lado, recuerda que debes actualizar la fecha también, o el año de esta para que funcione lo que buscas

Comment: y no tienes un código o algo así que pueda implementar o con lo que me pueda guiar?

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MySQL estás usando? ¿Te has planteado usar una vista para esto? O si es un `SELECT`, ¿por qué no hacer la cuenta directamente en el `SELECT`?

Comment: es una pregunta interesante, se podría reformular como:
a) sumar 1 perro por cada año transcurrido desde creado el registro?
b) sumar 1 perro por cada año transcurrido desde la fecha ingresada en el campo fecha?

Comment: Muy bueno punto @aloMalbarez, en mi respuesta había asumido que era desde la Fecha del registro, pero no tendría por qué ser así.

Comment: Es apartir de la fecha de registro, y no puedo con un select, porque no lo estoy viendo desde la base de datos, si no que uso una interfaz con JSP para ver la consulta, nada más que quiero saber como se puede hacer un script o un trigger que me compara la fecha de registro con la actual y que cuando hayan pasado 365 días me incremente un valor

Answer (score 1):

**1** Directamente en la consulta:

```
SELECT id, nombre,  
  perros+YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha) AS perros, fecha
FROM tabla_perros;
```

**2** Creando una vista (no modifica los datos originales):

```
CREATE VIEW tabla_perroshoy AS 
SELECT id, nombre,  
  perros+YEAR(CURDATE())-YEAR(fecha) AS perros, fecha
FROM tabla_perros;
```

y la consultas asi:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_perroshoy;
```

**3** Creando un evento (modifica los datos originales)

primero activar los eventos:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

luego:

```
CREATE EVENT update_tabla_perros
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-04-01 00:20:00'
DO 
UPDATE tabla_perros SET perro=perro+1 WHERE 1;
END;
```

Nota: para usar los eventos y por si el server se reinicia hay que modificar el my.cnf para que incluya la línea:

event_scheduler=ON

Nota2: lo armé medio al voleo así que no se como reacciona con años bisiestos

Comment: El tercero se puede poner de manera de trigger? y si es así como sería?

Comment: los triggers (disparadores) se ejecutan antes o después de insertar, modificar o borrar un registro. El paso del tiempo no está en ese grupo de posibilidades, para ello existen los eventos.  Ahora, si es posible armarlo con un trigger, pues si pero quedaría medio mutante y necesitaría que alguien o algo dispare el trigger. Como un select no dispara un trigger y pueden pasar 2 años sin que haya un update no alcanzas el estado de consistencia necesario para garantizar el asunto

Comment: Oh, wow, eso no lo sabia, entonces a fuerzas tengo que hacer un script

Comment: Si no puedes crear un event en el servidor, ni modificar el select, si habras de hacer el update mediante un script que se ejecute cada 1 año, pero si el script no se ejecuta en el mismo servidor y este cambia la ip o no hay conexion o se incendia la maquina que ejecuta el script (muchas cosas pasan en un año) el update no se realizará

Comment: Tienes razón, a manera que lo deje de manera manual

Answer (score 1):

RESOLVIENDO EL PROBLEMA CON JS:
Es la misma idea pero aplicada sólo al "AÑO"... ya sólo sería especificar por la fecha exacta que mencionan:

```
const anoInicial = 2018
var anoFinal = new Date().getFullYear()
var numeroDePerros = 5
var incrementoPerros = (numeroDePerros + (anoFinal - anoInicial))

console.log(incrementoPerros)
```

Answer (score 0):

ok te coloco este código de ejemplo de coo configurar un archivo php que haga el trabajo a trabes de cron en el panel de tu alojamiento web:

```
//Calcula la diferencia
function diferencia($X){

    $datetime1 = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d"));
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($X);
    $sale = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

    return $sale->format('%a');
}

$a = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tabla");
$t = $a->num_rows();

if($t>=1){
    //Nueva fecha en caso de actualización
    $fe = date("Y-m-d");
    //Recorro los resultados
    while($row = $a->fecht_object()){
        //Calculo la diferencia de días entre mla fecha registrada y la fecha de la consulta
        $diferencia = diferencia($row->fecha);
        //Si es un año
        if($diferencia === 365 ){
            //Actualizo los campos necesarios como lo son fecha y cantidad
            $a = $this->db->query("UPDATE tabla SET fecha = '$fe', cantidad = (cantidad + 1) WHERE id = '$row->id'");
        }
    }

}else{
    //No hace nada
}
```

Como te comente, puedes crearte un archivo parecido, colocarlo en tu servidor, y preparar un trabajo de cron en tu panel para que este se ejecute una vez al día, y verifique las fechas y ejecute las acciones correspondientes de actualización.

Comment: Y Por ejemplo si quiciera pasarloa JSP o JavaScript como sería o es de igual manera

Comment: Hermano, entonces alguna sugerencia de como podría ejecutar, con un bóton? o solito lo dejo como código embebido en la pagina jsp